# Specifying conditional prerequisites in WiX

Tags: wix, wix3.5, bootstrapper

I'm working on a WiX 3.5 project that installs a Windows service and a WPF client. The service uses SQL Server SMO and SQL Server CE, while the client uses DevExpress libraries. During installation, the user can choose to install either or both of the components. Is it possible for the MSI to check the SMO prerequisite if the server component is selected, and the DevExpress prerequisite if the client component is selected?

In other words, I shouldn't have to install DevExpress components on a server, and SMO/CE on the client. I've used the Windows SDK bootstrapper before to at least specify the SQL CE bootstrapper, but the bootstrapper would obviously have no knowledge of what components the user chose to select.

Will I have to ship separate client/server installs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're saying:

1) You'd like to ship one .msi that can be used for EITHER server OR client installs, correct?

2) You'd simply like to install some features (e.g. SQL Server SMO) for the server install, and different features (e.g. DevExpress) for the client install.  Correct?

3) If so, the answer is "Sure: why not?".

PS:
This link might be useful:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/alexshev/archive/2008/08/23/from-msi-to-wix-part-4-features-and-components.aspx

Comment: 1. It's more of a case of server AND/OR client installations; it's feasible that the end-user will be installing the client on to the server and running everything on localhost.

Comment: 3. I think that that was the conclusion that we were coming to :-)